# How to make a reusable textfield widget using the code below, so that I need not to write the entire textfields like name,age,emai,number etc

Tags: flutter, textfield

**Flutter**
How can I make a reusable textfield for different inputs using the code below? I'm unable to extract it properly.

```
                      Card(
                        elevation: 5,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _dobController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          validator: _validateInput,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                            hintText: 'Enter your date of birth',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            labelText: 'Dob',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Using widget
`CustomTextfieldWidget(hintText: "Example text", textInputType: TextInputType.text));`

Widget

```
 class CustomTextfieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextfieldWidget({Key? key, required this.hintText, required this.textInputType})
      : super(key: key);
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  
  @override
  _CustomTextfieldWidgetState createState() => _CustomTextfieldWidgetState();
}

class _CustomTextfieldWidgetState extends State<CustomTextfieldWidget> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        
        controller: myController,
        keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
          hintText: 'Enter your date of birth',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          labelText: widget.hintText,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In CustomTextfieldWidget(hintText: "Sample Text") , how will I pass my other custom attributes as controller and TextInputType, because controller will be different for different textields and TextInputType will be different for different fields, such as TextInputField.text and TextInputType.number for numbers. How will I pass these additional attributes in my custom widget?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, about `TextInputField.text`, I can’t find that, but I fixed `TextInputType` my answer has been edited

Comment: Thank you. My query is that how will I pass                                        
    onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },                                                                                                                       
  because here its not necessary that I'll have a string value, I may have Datetime value or number. So how to make it generic as you made the textInputType and hintText fields reusable /generic in your above solution?